# Don't keep original mp4 file after transcoding

Tags: files

I am on Drupal 6 using video module and ffmpeg to transcode videos. My source videos are in mp4. So I do not convert to mp4 but just copy the original file to the converted folder.

To save hdd space I want to remove the original file after transcoding. Is this possible? Any other suggestions?

Comment: HDD Space is cheap today, are you sure that time, effort and risk in deleting is worth it? And why do you need to make it automatic, can't you just make admin sweep it once a week?

Comment: @Mołot indeed I can make a sweep once a week :)

Comment: It will be way safer than to allow stupid mechanism delete user-provided data ;) Computers can't think, and are very fast at it :D